# Simple way to select a column from all databases on a server instance in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio. I tried this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%SomeColumn%'
```

I get this after executing above query:

[image]

However, I know that the column I specified in the WHERE is a valid column in one of my tables in one of my databases.

I just thought there would be maybe a table where each row has information on a column (including which table it belongs to and which database); so I could query for column 'SomeColumn' and then see which table(s) and database(s) it is in.

Comment: remove the table catalogue in the where clause and re-run your query. Probably it may be in a different table_catalogue

Comment: I tried as you said but my result set is still empty.

Comment: Have you tried sp_msforeachdb?  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1414/run-same-command-on-all-sql-server-databases-without-cursors/

Comment: The INFORMATION_SCHEMA data is database specific, so you'll have to do something like SQLChao suggests, or use a tool. Redgate makes a free SSMS plug in called SQL Search that does exactly this, and other cool tricks. https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/

Answer (score 0):

You can use sp_MSforeachdb

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)


SET @sql =
    'USE ?; 
    SELECT * 
    FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_CATALOG LIKE ''%%''
    AND   COLUMN_NAME LIKE ''%SomeColumn%'''

EXEC sys.sp_MSforeachdb @sql
```

Comment: [Careful with that undocumented proc](https://sqlblog.org/2010/12/29/a-more-reliable-and-more-flexible-sp_msforeachdb)

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'USE ? SELECT * FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE ''%SomeColumn%'''
```

The sp_msforeachdb sp will run your statement on all databases on your server.